# how to implement desire output by loop

Tags: c++, loops, plsql

how to produce following output by only using loop

```
iteration 1 = 54321 
iteration 2 = 43215
iteration 3 = 32145
iteration 4 = 21345 
iteration 5 = 12345
```

languages I could understand are C++,JavaScript,Php,PLSQL (PlSql is preferable)

Comment: The iteration output looks like bubble sort. Your problem specification isn't very specific.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11:
As you don't explain the logic, I do the simplest ^^:

```
int main () {
  const int numbers[5] = {54321, 43215, 32145, 21345, 12345};

  for (auto number : numbers) {
      std::cout << number << std::endl;
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was going to post this answer-- it follows the axiom : "Ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer."

Answer (score 1):

The result you presented seems to be an effect of a selection sort. You have to implement the following algorithm:

```
For i = N downto 2
    Let b = index of the biggest element from 1 to i
    if b != i
        Exchange item b with item i
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i, j;
    for(i=9; i>4; i--){
        for(j=5; j>=1; j--){
            cout<<( ( (i+j)%5 ) +1 );
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i, j;
for(i=9; i>4; i--){
    for(j=5; j>=1; j--){
        document.write( ( (i+j)%5 ) +1 );
    }
    document.write("<br />");
}
</script>
```

Comment: why you taking MODULUS ? . can't it possible with simple loops without using division  or multiplication with in the loop only out put statements can be used

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure

Since this appears to be homework it's really not right for me to give you an answer you can turn in - so I'll give you an answer in a slightly different language and you can just translate it:

```
(let [i [1 2 3 4 5]
      a [54321 43215 32145 21345 12345]]
  (doall (map #(println "Iteration " %1 " = " %2) i a)))
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

PL SQL Block

```
declare
  v_string varchar2(5) := '54321';
begin
  for i in 1 .. length(v_string) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('iteration ' || i || ' = ' || v_string);
    v_string := substr('54321', 2) || substr('54321', 1, 1) ;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nobody mentioned standard C++ algorithm std::rotate

```
const size_t N = 5;
int a[N] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

for ( size_t i = N; i != 0; i-- )
{
    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::rotate( a, a + 1, a + i );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check this code. I think it will solve your query regarding iterations you require.Thanks

DECLARE
  v_var        VARCHAR2(100);
  v_num        NUMBER;
  v_chnge      VARCHAR2(100);
  v_finl_chnge VARCHAR2(100);
  v_frst_str   VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  v_var:=trim('&enter');
  v_num:=LENGTH(v_var);
  dbms_output.put_line(LENGTH(v_var));
  FOR i IN 1..v_num
  LOOP
    v_frst_str  :=SUBSTR(v_var,-v_num,i);
    v_chnge     :=SUBSTR(v_var,i,v_num);
    v_finl_chnge:=(v_chnge||v_frst_str);
    dbms_output.put_line(SUBSTR(v_finl_chnge,-v_num,v_num));
  END LOOP;
END;

------------------------
OUTPUT
------------------------------
anonymous block completed
5
34562
45623
56234
62345
23456
```